# Discard elements of a String Array matching a specific criterion and Join them together without using indices

Tags: java, arrays, string, string-concatenation

I have a string array of full names with different surnames, i.e.

```
String[] tempArray = {"rakesh bhagat", "mayur suryavanshi", "prathamesh ambre", "akash tare", "abhi ingle", "rutvik patil"};
```

I want to create a new string of all names except one name, i.e.

```
temp = "rakesh bhagat, mayur suryavanshi, prathamesh ambre, akash tare, abhi ingle, rutvik patil";
```

So here I want to remove **"mayur suryavanshi"** from array without using index because I don't know index of that item, but I have certain condition like

```
if(tempArray[i].endsWith("suryawanshi")){}
```

Which I can use in for loop.
I tried to make new string with removing those item in for loop

```
String result = joiner.toString();
        
String temp = null;
        
for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
    if (tempArray[i].endsWith("suryavanshi")) {
        continue;
    }
    if (temp == null) {
        temp = tempArray[i];
    } else {
        temp = temp + ", " + tempArray[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid concatenating string in the loop, each concatenation `str1 + str2` in a new string stored as a separate object. As the consequence of this, lots of intermediate strings which you don't need would be created.

Use `StringBuilder` or other built-in mechanisms when you need to join together more than just a couple of strings.

## Collectors.joining()

It can be done with Stream API using built-in Collector [`joning()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining(java.lang.CharSequence)):

```
String[] tempArray = {"rakesh bhagat", "mayur suryavanshi", "prathamesh ambre", "akash tare", "abhi ingle", "rutvik patil"};
    
String result = Arrays.stream(tempArray)
    .filter(str -> !str.endsWith("suryavanshi")) // retain only elements which don't end with "suryavanshi"
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

## StringJoiner

Alternatively, you can use a so-called [enhanced `for`-loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) (also known as *for-each*) and [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/StringJoiner.html) :

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(", ");
    
for (String str : tempArray) {
    if (str.endsWith("suryavanshi")) continue;
    
    joiner.add(str);
}
        
String result = joiner.toString();
```